# How to create instance of class in XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to create simple utility class that has no visual elements and create it in XAML so I can define databindings. I tried to create class derived from `DependencyObject` and create it in `Window.Resources` section but it doesn't call any constructor.

Comment: I've found dirty workaround for this problem - to place `FindResource("myClass");` in main form constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like instances are created when you actually use them. I've found dirty workaround for this problem - to place `FindResource("myClass");` in main form constructor.

Answer (score 6):

You can instantiate your class in the app.xaml, just add your namespace to it with

```
xmlns:yourNamespace="clr-namespace...."
```

It is easy the intellisense helps.

And then in Application.Resources you create your class

```
<Application.Resources>
   <yourNamespace:YourClass x:Key="yourClassInstanteName" />      
</Application.Resources>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I did that. The problem is that class instance isn't created at run time (just try to drop breakpoint in constructor).

Comment: Looks like instances are created when you actually *use* them

Comment: yes but your Bindings are using it so it should instantiate it

Comment: Nope, it isn't instantiated even when binding sources are changed. I think bindings themselves aren't instantiated too.

Comment: Could you share your XAML bindings, or one for example? Just curious because you use converters this way too and they work. You use StaticResource to bind?

Comment: Here's teh codez http://pastebin.com/sZkpmFpX http://pastebin.com/9E5sCNDP, form should change it's title when button is pressed.

Comment: Did you try to move the Test class from windows.Resources to App.Resources and then use StaticResource Binding in the MainWindow Title.

Comment: Why don't you bind Directly to the MainWindow.Src property? Sorry that i ask something like that but lately i use MVVM and there it is done a bit differently. :)

Comment: In real application it's binded to application's settings via custom markup extension derived from binding class. Also the purpose of properties is completely different.

Answer (score 1):

I know i am posting on an old Question but i came across this while trying to find the answers myself. The code big L posted was indeed correct:

```
xmlns:yourNamespace="clr-namespace...."
```

Place a copy in the Application Resources:

```
<Application.Resources>
   <yourNamespace:YourClass x:Key="yourClassInstanteName" />      
</Application.Resources>
```

The additional key to this information is that the class needs to have a default constructor. So in the Class source you should have a method like so:

```
public yourClassName()
```