# XAML- creating an instance of a class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, build-error

I am trying to create an instance of a C# class from within the XAML markup of my application.

I am trying to use the instance of the C# class inside a `<StackPanel></StackPanel>` tag, inside a `<TabItem></TabItem>` tag that I have nested in the `<TabControl></TabControl>` tag where I have declared the namespace that the C# class belongs to:

```
<TabControl xmlns:agent="RAgent">
    <TabItem Header="R">
        <StackPanel>
            ...
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header = "BClass">
        <StackPanel>
            <agent:BClass />
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

The C# class `BClass` is defined with:

```
namespace RAgent{
    public partial class BClass : UserControl{
        public BClass(){
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I know that the C# code compiles and runs correctly, as I have previously run this separate to the rest of the application. However, when I currently try to build my code, I get a compile error in the XAML, on the line:

```
<agent:BClass />
```

which says:

> The name "BClass" does not exist in the namespace "RAgent"

But `BClass` clearly does exist in the namespace `RAgent`, as I have declared the namespace at the top of the `BClass.cs` file with `namespace RAgent{`...

What am I doing wrong here? Am I trying to instantiate `BClass` incorrectly from within the XAML file? How should I do this?

**Edit**

Ok, so I've edited my `.xaml` file a bit based on the answer at [How to create instance of class in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668726/how-to-create-instance-of-class-in-xaml), and on other bits of information I've picked up from various places.

I've added the line:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RAgent">
```

to the top of the file, and then removing the use of `xmlns` in the `<TabControl>` tag, and trying to create an instance of the class through `local`:

```
<TabControl>
    ...
    <TabItem Header="BClass">
        <StackPanel>
            <local:BClass x:Name="BClass" />
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

However, I now get a compile error on the line where I'm trying to instantiate the `BClass`:

```
<local:BClass x:Name="BClass" />
```

which says:

> A value of type 'BClass' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'.

I tried removing the `<StackPanel></StackPanel>` tags, and although this removed the above compile error, it left me with one that says:

> The name "BClass" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:RAgent"- which it clearly does, as shown by the definition of `BClass`...

Anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: Did you tried to add `x:Key` for this declaration? So the code should look like this `<agent:BClass x:Key="testObject" />`. Or maybe there is problem with `partial` keyword.

Comment: I've just given this a go, but still get the same compile error, and now also get one that says `A value of type 'BClass' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'`

Comment: xmlns:agent="`clr-namespace`:RAgent" maybe?

Comment: That's what I have... `<TabControl xmlns:agent="clr-namespace:RAgent">`, and then inside `<TabItem><StackPanel>`, I have put `<agent:RBrowser/>`, with the closing tags following: `</StackPanel></TabItem>`

Comment: I've edited my OP to show how I've tried to resolve this issue, and the issues I'm now getting with trying to create an instance of `BClass`...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you creating the `TabControl`in your MainApp and then each `TabItem`as a `UserControl` in your project. Then, you can easily instantiate your classes in the corresponding tab by doing
`<local:BClass x:Name="BClass"/>`

Check [Tabs in different XAML views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5555051/7586301) and [How to create and use an instance of a class in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59070675/7586301) for a better understanding